# Deleting the "cached" field names for a large CSV file

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, geocoding, csv

Using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.1

I have a large CSV file (36MB with about 600,000 records) that contains single addresses that I want to geocode.  The file is called "SingleAddresses.csv"  The file contains 5 fields.  When I first loaded the file into ArcMap, I had misnamed some of the field names, and so my field names were "SegID", "FromStNo", "Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3".   So I closed ArcMap, reopened my file in Notepad++, changed the field names to "Address", "City", "Zone1", "Zone2",  "Zone3".  However, when I open up ArcMap again and add the SingleAddresses.csv file again, the old (original) field names show up.

It seems as though ArcMap is caching the field names for the "C:\My Files\SingleAddresses.csv" file.  If I move that file to a different directory and then open it in ArcMap, the field names show up correctly.  If I keep that file in the same directory but rename it (SingleAddresses2.csv) and then open it in ArcMap, the field names show up correctly.  But as long as I keep the same file name in the same directory, it still shows the old field names, even if I delete the original file and create a new empty SingleAddresses.csv file.  It also still shows the old field names if I import that file into a new (different) map.

Note that I cannot duplicate this if the original file is a small file.  The problem only occurs if the file that I originally use is "big"...

Is there a cache somewhere that I can delete that would eliminate this problem?  It seems as though ArcMap caches the field names for a hard-coded file name.  It is really annoying...

Comment: do you have xx files in C:\Documents and Settings\<user_profile>\Local Settings\Temp or C:\Users\<user_profile>\AppData\Local\Temp http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m100000009000000

Comment: Nothing relevant that I can see... a few files with modified dates in the last couple of days, but none related to ArcMap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a schema.ini in the same folder as your .csv, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

go to the options in arcmap and clear the cache.
[image: cache]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried this... doesn't work... I tried to clear the cache and then reload it without closing ArcMap, and also clearing the cache then restarting ArcMap... neither solved the problem...